# Matplotlib event_handling line picker

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, interactive, picker

This [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html) makes it possible to click a legend and thereby change a plot.

I want to do something similar, but then not by clicking the legend, just by clicking the line in the plot. I tried to do it like this:

```
self.ax =  self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
data = NP.array(2,10)  #filled with numbers
self.x = NP.arange(2)
for line in range(len(data[0,:])):
    self.ax.plot(self.x, data[:,line], picker=5)
```

In every loop, an extra line is plotted. One line consists of 2 points, so it draws a straight line. But now every loop, the picker is the same, so no matter which line I click, the commands I wrote to manipulate the clicked line always affect the first line.
Is there a way to improve this?

Comment: Can you include a complete _minimal_ example in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you wanting something like this?  When a line is clicked, it will be hidden, and when the "empty" location is clicked again, it will be shown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(1, 10):
    ax.plot(x, i * x + x, picker=5)

def on_pick(event):
    event.artist.set_visible(not event.artist.get_visible())
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is already more interesting. But I would also need the number of the line I clicked: All lines are constructed in a specific order and other graphs need to be updated when one of these lines is clicked, so I need the index of the line I clicked. my function on_pick therefore contains "ind = event.ind" but as I said, this always returns ind = 0 when the lines are plotted in a loop function

Comment: @Jan - Actually, `event.ind` will refer to the individual verticies of the individual line.  If you want the index of the overall line in the order that they're plotted, use `ax.lines.index(event.artist)`.  You can even do `ax = event.artist.axes; ax.lines.index(event.artist)` if you need to work with multiple axes or don't want to deal with passing the axes object around.