# How to realise matplotlib line picker by using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter-canvas

I would like to pick lines that have been drawn on an image by using `cv2.line` and do something with them. To realise that I had a look on [matplotlibs picker](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) and even found a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201869/matplotlib-event-handling-line-picker). As I am going to use `tkinter` for GUI I added it to my MWE.

**Code from example which works fine:**

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

root = Tk.Tk()
root.iconify()

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(1, 10):
    ax.plot(x, i * x + x, picker=5)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def on_pick(event):
    event.artist.set_visible(not event.artist.get_visible())
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)

root.mainloop()
```

**Now my code using OpenCV which does not work:**

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
   import tkinter as Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np
import cv2

root = Tk.Tk()
root.iconify()

img = np.zeros([100,100,3],dtype=np.uint8)
img.fill(255)
cv2.line(img,(10,10),(60,90),(100,149,237),2)

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.plot()
ax.imshow(img)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def onpick1(event):
    event.artist.set_visible(not event.artist.get_visible())        
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', onpick1)

root.mainloop()
```

In both examples `onpick1` should set the lines visibility on or off by a single mouse click but it doesn't. My assumption is that it has something to do with the way it is plotted or how I draw the lines (`ax.plt` vs `cv2.line`). I would be very happy about any help. Thanks!

Comment: You are assuming that `cv2.line` creates an object that can be understood by matplotlib. This is not the case. Instead `cv2.line` just changes some pixels in the `img` image. What you could do is create two images, one with and one without the line and upon a click on any pixel that contains the line change the image. Seems very complicated though. So why not use the matplotlib line as in the first example?

Comment: That was the missing information I needed. Thanks! Sticking to matplotlib line really makes sense in my situation.